# Joining 3 tables by one specific field

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got three tables of the following structures:

```
1.table - product_name:

product_id (unique)
product_name
(...)

2. table - pro
product_id
pro
(...)

3. table - con
product_id
con
(...)
```

The idea is that each product can be assigned infinite number of pros and cons.

Now my aim is to have one query that, in the case when 3-3 pros and cons are assigned to a specific product, would return *exactly* 6 lines. 3 with the con column empty and pro column with the values, and vice versa.

I've tried a few things, and the closest I got to the solution was:

```
SELECT * FROM product_name pn 
 JOIN pro p on pn.product_id = p.product_id 
 JOIN con c on pn.product_id = c.product_id 
WHERE pn.id = 1
```

Now this query would return 9 lines, not 6. It returns all 3 pro-s exactly 3 times, attached to each of the cons. What I'm getting:

```
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    Pro - 1 Con - 1 
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    Pro - 1 Con - 2 
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    Pro - 1 Con - 3 
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    Pro - 2 Con - 1 
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    Pro - 2 Con - 2 
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    Pro - 2 Con - 3 
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    Pro - 3 Con - 1 
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    Pro - 3 Con - 2 
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    Pro - 3 Con - 3
```

What I'm after is:

```
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    Pro - 1 NULL
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    Pro - 2 NULL    
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    Pro - 3 NULL    
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    NULL    Con - 1 
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    NULL    Con - 2 
1   Razor EcoSmart Metro HD electric scooter    NULL    Con - 3
```

I tried to fiddle around with GROUP BY and DISTINCT but still couldn't make it work. I guess they are not the solution anyway.

What am I missing?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - presented as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: @jarlh I edited my question accordingly, hope it clarifies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend storing pros and cons in only one table.  That would simplify this a lot.

But, you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_name pn LEFT JOIN
     ((SELECT p.product_id, p.pro, null as con
       FROM pros p
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT c.product_id, null as pro, con
       FROM cons c
      )
     ) pc
     USING (product_id);
```

Note:  You can include more columns in the subquery.  You just need to include them from both tables.

Comment: Thanks - this query throws an error saying column 'product_id' is invalid in 'from clause'. Any idea why?

You are right, having pros and cons in the same table would simplify this, and I am even considering restructuring my whole database accordingly (I'm in an early phase of development, so that would be easy) - but now I won't let this thing go until I have this figured out.

Although based on your solution it is not necessarily beginners' stuff.

Comment: @ZsoltBalla . . . Yes.  I originally wrote the query with `select *` in the subqueries.  Then I listed the columns but left out the column used for the joins.